# How can I prompt a user for input in a CLI tool while being able to pipe the output of the tool to another program?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a CLI tool to encrypt & embed secrets in docker-compose files. I require the user to interactively input the password for the decryption  through stdin.

Unfortunately, this means I'm not able to do something like this since I won't get the dialog asking me for the password:

```
myfancytool decrypt docker-compose.yml | docker-compose -f - up -d
```

Is there any way to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eprint!` or `eprintln!` macro to print the prompt to stderr instead of stdout.  Then it will still go the terminal even if stdout is redirected to a pipe.

Comment: This looks like an abuse of stderr. Asking for a password is not an error. What if a user wants to redirect stderr to a log file? On Linux, you should be able to write directly to `/dev/tty` and have this shown on the terminal, no matter whether you are piping or not.

Comment: Seconding @mcarton, this is one of the rare cases where writing directly to `/dev/tty` is the right thing to do.